# Access to different databases, prevent user errors PHP

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, security

I'm developing a tool that allows user to change database connection.
So user has a select box where he selects the desire database. I have a total of 4 different databases, but structure is the same in all, only data change.

If user works only with 1 open tab, I don't have any kind of problem. But if user works with few tabs , a lot of security problems can happen.

For example:
Tab 1 - User wants edit a row from database 1
In the same time, user change Tab2 to database 3.
So when he is going to save tab 1, probably it would save to database 3, as it was the last change.

I'm saving the selected database on $_SESSION var.

My code right now, I have a form where user selects the database. And on _init.php I have a simple switch case that require a different config.php depending of selected database.

Some ideas how i can prevent errors like this happen?

Comment: Is user education an option? "Close all other tabs before touching this setting." If not then you are going to have an endless uphill battle. Imagine this scenario: Conn1 open in Tab1, Tab2 opened and switched to Conn2. Data updated in Tab1 and the page refreshes since you are not using AJAX so the user does not see the changes which they have made.

Comment: That's is the problem @MonkeyZeus. But we can't trust an user :(

Answer (score 0):

If you store the active connection in $_SESSION, there can be only one active connection regardless the number of tabs you open in your browser as the session is shared across tabs.

Instead, you can give a counter or a numeric identifier for each connection:

Example:

```
1 = connection 1
2 = connection 2
...
```

If the user changes the connection from your select box, use a redirect a send a GET parameter with the connection number.

Example:

- if I choose connection 1 the browser redirects to index.php?cn=1
- If in another tab I use connection 2, the browser redirects me to index.php?cn=2

You will need always to send your connection id by GET or POST, and receive it instead of looking it in your $_SESSION var.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If *each concurrent tab* is permitted to use a separate database connection, then *each concurrent tab* will need to specify that information when posting requests to the server.

This could be as simple as including the identifier for the database in a hidden field in each form.  When the user selects a different database on that page, update that hidden field.  (Mostly guessing on the "hidden field" structure here, since we don't know how your forms are laid out.  But the point is that the form should contain this value.)

This becomes an overall more RESTful approach, moving away from session state and toward a state transfer driven by the page itself.  Which in general is a good thing.

Basically, since the request for the action being performed (saving a record) needs to know where to save it, include that piece of information in the request itself rather than trying to juggle that information server-side.

Comment: Hi @David. For all tabs should be the same database connection. But if user change in one tab, I only know that he changed in another tab, after reload page. That's the problem. And we don't have any API here.

Comment: @62009030: It sounds like you're going to want to define the user experience before defining the technical implementation.  If the user has two tabs open and changes the database in one tab, what *should* happen?  (And I'm not sure what you mean about an API, how is that relevant?)

Comment: If user changes DB in on tab1, i can't allow him to save anything in tab2 (if it has different DB connection)

Comment: @62009030: Then this approach would allow that, in combination with your current approach.  If you store the "current DB" in session state, then any time a form is submitted which specifies a DB other than the "current" one you can return an error, refresh the page with a friendly message, etc.

Comment: So do you mean I add a hidden field in all forms with current DB. Than before save something new , compare if SESSION var is the same as the hidden field. if yes saves, if not displays a error. is that? Thanks

Comment: @62009030: That's the idea, yes.  Alternatively you might keep web socket connections open to the pages and whenever the database changes in one you could handle that change in the other open pages, but that might over-complicate the actual need here.  It really depends on the intended user experience.  If simply "don't allow them to save" is the requirement, then allowing them to *try* to save and returning a helpful message in the response seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly I would take a different approach to your issue.

Set up sub-domains on your server which point to the same exact web folder and have hard-coded DB connection settings.

```
db1.example.com
db2.example.com
db3.example.com
db4.example.com
```

Now the user will have to log into the correct sub-domain in order to perform operations on the desired DB so `session_start()` will actually create a unique session per sub-domain.

The user will be able to have 4 tabs open without the fear of using the wrong DB.

So your `db_config.php` file can look like this:

```
switch($sub_domain)
{
    case 'db1.example.com':
        // Code for connecting to DB1
        break;
    case 'db2.example.com':
        // Code for connecting to DB2
        break;
    case 'db3.example.com':
        // Code for connecting to DB3
        break;
    case 'db4.example.com':
        // Code for connecting to DB4
        break;
}
```

As for the idea with creating a `<select>` box for choosing your DB, you can just implement some JS to open a new tab pointing to the correct sub-domain.

Comment: Hi @MonkeyZeus. Actually it was our previous approach. But Right now guys want to change it, to have all in the same domain, to faster change database connection

Comment: @62009030 In that case I would recommend creating a way to auto-login the user when using the `<select>` box to switch DBs. Following through with the `$_SESSION` idea is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Well, I will have to implement it with some security, I don't know yet how, but boss wants it so ...

Comment: @62009030 "implement with some security" <- I assume this refers to my comment about the "auto-login" approach? Anyways, is the boss your direct supervisor; preferably someone that has a computer degree? Or are they someone higher up the ladder such as the CFO? Is merging the databases an option? I would really like to know why you have several DBs with the same structure? Is this a product which you guys sell to clients and each client gets their own DB to mitigate a system-breaking change?

Comment: @62009030 Can you identify who the users of your system are exactly?

Comment: I can't talk so much about this. But we have a database per continent. In order to have data well organized they decided to separate per continent. And each database has TB of data , so is not good approach to merge them

Comment: I am sorry to hear that you are in such a tough spot but I stand by my answer 100%. Going down the `$_SESSION` db-switching route is prone to issues. You might not be the cause of these issues but as soon as another programmer wants to add a new feature or fix a bug then they will have to deal with the overhead of knowing how and when to add the DB connection to post/get requests in all of your forms and AJAX calls, and how to handle it on the back-end. If you are interested in hearing about my "auto-login" implementation then I will be happy to update my answer with that info.

Comment: I have already implemented an auto-login, but in this case, is not what I need :( Thanks anyway!

Comment: @62009030 Good luck to you :)